# Saga never transitions into next state despite yielding an action that is sent

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

This saga works with the `LOGIN_SUCCESS` action and persists the data correctly. However after that it never reacts to `LOGOUT_SUCCESS`

```
function *persistAccount() {
  while (true) {
    const result = yield take([actions.LOGIN_SUCCESS, actions.USER_UPDATED, actions.LOGOUT_SUCCESS])
    console.info("Got persist action")
    switch (result.type) {
      case actions.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      case actions.USER_UPDATED:
        console.info("Updating credentials")
        if (result.access_token) {
          localStorage["access_token"] = result.access_token
        }
        if (result.user) {
          localStorage["user"] = JSON.stringify(result.user)
        }
        break
      case action.LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
        debugger
        console.info("Clearing credentials")
        localStorage.removeItem("access_token")
        localStorage.removeItem("user")
        break
    }
  }
  console.info("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!EXIT")
}
```

It also never finishes, cause this would print the text in the last line to the console.

Whats going on?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. You sure you don't have a typo somewhere? Also make sure that the `LOGOUT_SUCCESS` action is actually being dispatched.

Comment: yes it is dispatched. I see it in the redux logger output. Other sagas react to the action just ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe it took me this long to see. It's a typo:

```
case action.LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
```

needs to be:

```
case actions.LOGOUT_SUCCESS: // "actions" instead of "action"
```

Comment: Oh yes! But action is undefined. How come there was no error thrown?

Comment: TBH, not sure... might be an issue with how `redux-saga` handles errors